# Password change form URL in Django admin cannot find user with correct ID

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm having some trouble with my admin settings. I am using a custom user model (called Org, for context), and everything works perfectly in the admin except for the password change form. For clarity, I'm talking about the little form that says

"Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this user’s password, but you can change the password using this form."

However, when I click on "this form", I'm redirected back to the admin homepage, with the warning "Org with ID '40/password (40 being the ID)' doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?"

Examples of inline and admin

````py
# all inlines look like this:
class OrgContactInfoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OrgContactInfo

@admin.register(Org)
class OrgAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [OrgContactInfoInline, OrgInfoInline, OrgLocationInline, ItemInline]
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = Org
    ordering = ("-org_name",)```
````

Important forms

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
        label=mark_safe(
            "Your password must:<br />-Be longer than 8 characters<br />-Have an uppercase and lowercase characters<br />-Use a special character/number"
        ),
    )
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Org
        fields = ["org_name"]


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Org
        fields = ["org_name"]
```

URLs

```
urlpatterns = [
    #my urls
    path('', include('apps.homepage.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('apps.accounts.urls')),
    path('mynonprofit/', include('apps.dashboard.urls')),

    #django urls
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r".*", TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
]
```

And finally, the model

```
class Org(AbstractUser):
    objects: CustomUserManager = CustomUserManager()

    org_name = models.CharField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=100,
        null=False,
        error_messages={"unique": "Orginization with this name already exists"},
    )
    username = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    email = None
    USERNAME_FIELD = "org_name"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ()  # type: ignore

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.org_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Org"
        verbose_name_plural = "Orgs"
```

I've tried pretty much everything except playing around with my urls.py file, and I'm doing that as I write this. I've changed the forms, admin, models, etc., but to no avail.